# DataTables search by select input + remove actual search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables and so far it has been great.
The problem is that I can't say that I know enough jquery/js to be able to edit some of it functionalities:

Right now I'm using this: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

But I would want to only have 2 selects that work the same way like the ones in the link and show in the right corner(head of table) instead of the common search box.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `dom: 'lrtip'` to remove the search box, see **https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom**

Comment: this is a plugin that might be able to help you with this that is easy to configure.  http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://code.buzzword-cloud.com/post/2017/05/02/datatables-column-searching) I did. The dom attribute will help you remove the search filter initially. `dom: irtp` will just render the info, processing, table and pagination elements. Then do the search similar to How I did by using the `.search()` on the columns. [Here is the API reference to search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())